# Prove that if $W \subseteq V$ is a subspace s.t. $W \cap W^\perp = \{0\}$, then $V = W\oplus W^\perp$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, bilinear-form, symmetric-functions

**EDIT: Please do not waste your time on this question! I missed a hypothesis (namely that $\beta$ is non-degenerate) which makes this whole question trivial.**

Let $\beta:V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ be a symmetric bilinear form.

In class we've defined:

- If $W \subseteq V$ is a subspace, then $W^\perp := \{v \in V \mid \beta(v,w)=0 \text{ for all }w \in W\}$.
- The form $\beta$ is non-degenerate if $V^\perp = \{0\}$

We've also proved the proposition

- If $\beta$ is non-degenerate and $W\subseteq V$ is a subspace, then $\dim V = \dim W + \dim W^\perp$.

How can I prove the following corollary?

> Prove that if $W \subseteq V$ is a subspace s.t. $W \cap W^\perp = \{0\}$, then $V = W\oplus W^\perp$.

This is neither a homework question nor an exercise, but was stated in the lecture notes as a proof. I'm presuming that this should be something easy, but I can't see how to use the proposition to get this.

Comment: If $V$ is finite-dimensional, we have $W\cap W^{\perp} = \{0\} \implies V = W \oplus W^{\perp}$ also if $V^{\perp} \neq \{0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\dim(W + W^\perp)=\dim W +\dim W^\perp -\dim (W\cap W^\perp)=\dots=\dim V$$ and so
$$W+W^\perp=V.$$

Comment: Sorry, I did not pay enough attention.

Comment: If $V$ is finite-dimensional, then we always have $\dim W + \dim W^{\perp} \geqslant \dim V$. With $\varphi \colon V \to V^{\ast};\, w \mapsto \beta(w,\,\cdot\,)$, $W^{\perp}$ is the annihilator of $\varphi(W)$, so $\dim W^{\perp} = \dim V^{\ast} - \dim \varphi(W) \geqslant \dim V - \dim W$ since $\dim V^{\ast} = \dim V$ and $\dim \varphi(W) \leqslant \dim W$.